# scroll horizantal of an matrix of image buttons

Tags: android, scroll

I am having 30 image buttons, which are to be arranged 10 columns and 3 rows, But i am not able to have a scrollview to arrange. please help me out.

Comment: Include more details otherwise no one would be able to help you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GridLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.example">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="900dp" >

       <!-- your buttons -->

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Use the support library v7